# How to pass a array to a constructor and use it in a class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor

This is my main method, i am trying to get back into coding, for i failed at it repeatedly in school. I want to take an array from my main method with user input from a loop, and pass it to a constructor in my "TestScoresTwo.java" class. I want to then take that array and use it to sum the values and find the average in a method in the class, and then return the sum.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.*;


public class labBookFortyTwo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{


Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the amount of grades there are ");

int size = myInput.nextInt();

double grade = 0;

double[] myArray = new double[size];

for(int count = 0; count < myArray.length; count++)
{
    System.out.println("enter grade ");

    grade = myInput.nextDouble();

    myArray[count] = grade;

    System.out.println("grade is " + myArray[count] );

}

TestScoresTwo myScore = new TestScoresTwo(myArray, size);

double avg = myScore.avgGrade();

System.out.println("avg is" + avg);


}

}
```

This is my TestScoresTwo.java Class.

```
public class TestScoresTwo
{

int size = 0;

double[] tScore = new double[size];

double sum = 0;



public TestScoresTwo(double[] scores ,int sizE)
{

    double[] tScore = scores;

    size = sizE;

}




public double avgGrade()
{


        for(int count = 0; count < tScore.length ; count++) 
        {
            sum = tScore[count] + sum;

        }


    double avg = sum / size;

    return avg;

}

}
```

When it compiles my output is:
"Please enter the amount of grades there are"
3
"enter grade"
11
"grade is 11.0"
50
"grade is 50.0"
70
"grade is 70.0"
"avg" is 0.0"
"Press any key to continue..."

So for some reason in my class TestScoresTwo.java, the for loop inst being entered, and im not sure why. They are two separate files , and i cant think of any other information to include. Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug.  If you don't have an interactive debugger, insert System.out.println statements to show your progress and the values that are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your array `double[] tScore = new double[size];` to be of zero size.  You intended to replace it with a new array in your constructor here:

```
double[] tScore = scores;
```

However, all you did is declare a local variable of the same name, and assign the parameter to it, which immediately goes out of scope at the end of the constructor.  The `for` loop appears not to be entered, because `tScore` is still empty and of zero length.

Remove `double[]` so that `tScore` resolves to your instance variable and get assigned properly.

```
tScore = scores;
```

Also, it's confusing to see a parameter named `sizE` and an instance variable named `size`.  It's common to use `this` to refer to the instance variable, so that they can be named the same name and yet be clear.  Try naming the parameter `size` also, and use this line in your constructor:

```
this.size = size;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it worked, and the reason i use sizE, is because using this. is confusing to me, but i will try and consider it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your proble; is in `TestScoresTwo` class:

```
public TestScoresTwo(double[] scores ,int sizE)
{
    double[] tScore = scores;
    size = sizE;
}
```

tScore is local to the constructor. So you're assigning the passed variable to a local variable, which is lost once the end of the constructor is reached.

So when you call `avgGrade()` to calculate the average, the array it,s calculating the average from is empty.

Replace it by:

```
public class TestScoresTwo
{
    int size = 0;
    double[] tScore; // no need to create it here, it's already created and filled in outside
    double sum = 0;

    public TestScoresTwo(double[] scores ,int sizE)
    {
        this.tScore = scores; // "this." added for clarity
        this.size = sizE; // "this." added for clarity
    }
```